# Appending different field in C++

Tags: c++

```
char  name;
char* id;
int   salary;
char  department[5];
```

How I want to append all these datas into a single stream of data? eg: JoeA1250002 where Joe is the name, A12 is the member id, 5000 is the salary and 2 is the department number.

Thank you

Comment: `Joe` cannot possibly be the `name`, since the `name` is only a single character. Also, don't go around throwing `char *` in people's face and pretend you're writing C++...

Comment: Replace `char *` by `string` and Wrap them up in a nicely named structure.

Comment: You could stream the data like that. But how then how are you supposed to separate it back into its components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `name` is actually defined `char*`, and you are really using C++, you would use a `stringstream`:

```
std::ostringstream output;
output << name << id << salary << department;

std::string const value = output.str(); // eg: JoeA1250002
```

Comment: Is it possible to copy this const value into a char?

Comment: @Kiran: You want to go back to C? Something like `strdup( output.str().c_str() )` should work...

Comment: But strdup is not available in C++ STL. Is there a C++ approach?

Comment: @Kiran: `malloc` and `strcpy` then? The C++ approach would be to use `std::string` to start with.

Comment: I am trying  char* nm; size_t length = strlen(value);
 nm = new char[(strlen(value))+ 1];
 memcpy(nm, value , length + 1); but it is still giving me error?

Comment: @Kiran: Is that `value` the `std::string` I defined? To get the C-string representation of an `std::string` one has to call `.c_str()`.